# Javascript Unittest Jest Time Interval from a Day

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am getting stuck with testing my Interval from a Day.
Maybe someone can explain me what I am doing wrong.

**This is what I want to test**

```
export const getMondayFromDay = (date) => {
  const monday = new Date(date);
  const day = monday.getDay();
  monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1));
  monday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return monday;
}
```

**My failed test**

```
    it("returns day interval from monday", () => {
        const mockMondayFromDay = new Date('2021-01-04');
        const expectedFrom = new Date('2021-01-04');
        expectedFrom.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const expectedTo = new Date('2021-01-04');
        expectedTo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

        jest.fn(() => mockMondayFromDay);
        const { from , to } = getMondayFromDay(new Date('2021-01-04'));
        expect(from).toEqual(expectedFrom);
        expect(to).toEqual(expectedTo);
    });
```

[image: failed Test]

Answer (score 1):

Your `getMondayFromDay` function only returns a single date (the previous monday (or the day if it's already a monday) according to the date given).

So `from` and `to` are undefined here:
`const { from , to } = getMondayFromDay(new Date('2021-01-04'));`.

Your tests could be:

```
// test if the same date is returned if it's a monday
const monday = getMondayFromDay(new Date('2021-01-04'));
expect(monday).toEqual(expectedFrom);
```

```
// test if the previous monday is returned if the date is not a monday
const monday2 = getMondayFromDay(new Date('2021-01-05'));
expect(monday2).toEqual(expectedFrom);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a Solution now:

```
    it("returns day interval from monday", () => {
        const expectedFrom = new Date('2021-06-14');
        expectedFrom.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const expectedTo = new Date('2021-06-14');
        expectedTo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

        const monday = getMondayFromDay(new Date('2021-06-16'));
        expect(monday.getDate()).toEqual(14);
        expect(monday.getMonth()).toEqual(5);
        expect(monday.getFullYear()).toEqual(2021);
    });
```

Comment: It works but my answer is more complete, you are only testing a single case (not a monday).